# Take some items from a collection in Clojure, why subvec is slower than take&drop?

Tags: clojure

Is there an idomatic way of take some items from a collection?

Here is how I did:

```
(time (drop 30 (take 70 (range 10001))))
;> "Elapsed time: 0.049797 msecs"
;> (30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69)

(time (subvec (vec (range 10001)) 30 70))
;> "Elapsed time: 2.072258 msecs"
;> [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
```

Question:

1. Why the subvec method is slower than the take & drop approach?
2. What's the idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [vec](http://conj.io/1.6.0/clojure.core/vec/) isn't lazy, so you are creating an entire array of 10001 items, then taking a sub vector of it, whereas drop/take/range are lazy so only supply the items you need. You don't do anything with the last (10001-70) items, so they aren't created/used and thus take no time
2. your first version is idiomatic enough for what you're doing.

Comment: Ah, Lazy-ness matters! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison wasn't carried out in a proper way.

A single `time` is not enough to compare two code blocks. You should use `dotimes` to repeat them for a number of times so that the difference of execution times are more reliable:

```
;; returns the time it took to repeat running the code 1000 times
(time (dotimes [i 1000] your-code-block))
```

In your second code block, you convert the lazy sequence returned by `range` to vector with `vec` which took some extra time, too:

```
(vec (range 10001))
```

You can use the `time` + `dotimes` technique to compare the above with `(range 10001)` itself.

I hope this will be a foundation for your further exploration.

Comment: Thank you so much for teach me the `(time (dotimes ...))` method. I'll use it from now on. This is quite helpful. The people in Clojure community is really great.

Comment: the language forces them to be so :)

Comment: for proper microbenchmarking, you can also use [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium)